# Can variables from the main script be read inside of class functions?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I'm learning ActionScript 2.0 by dissecting some freely available source code and modifying it, and I've run into a little hitch.

I've got 3 .as files that go with my .fla and they are:

"script.as" contains all of the basic functions that go with the flash interface I've built.
"skin.as" contains the interface skin class declaration and class functions.
"defaultskin.as" contains a class declaration and functions that extend the "skin" class.

The first frame of the .fla simply #includes "script.as" and I have linked the "interface" movieclip (which is my main flash interface) to the "defaultskin" class through the right click / properties menu under ActionScript linkage.

I've got a variable declared in "script.as" with a simple var statement. Can this variable be read in one of the functions inside of "skin.as" in one of the class functions as is? Or do I need to do something special for it to be readable to that class?

How can this be done without making the variable a public static and without passing it as an argument of the function?

For additional clarification, script.as looks something like this (assume that m_interface is the name of the movieclip object):

```
//imports

var myVar;

onLoad()
{
 m_interface.Initialize();
}
```

skin.as looks something like:

```
//imports

class skin
{
 //variable declarations

 public function skin()
 {
  // code
 }

 function Initialize()
 {
  trace(myVar);
 }
}
```

without writing all of the fluff code, defaultskin.as declares a class as such:

```
class defaultskin extends skin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default then you use `var` it gives it `internal` access modifier.
so it could be accessed only by the class or any class within the same package
so if you don't use any other modifiers, or not pass this varible somehow to your class, the answer is "no, it is not accessable"
if you use `public` modifier, you give access to variable to any class, but there is some other restrictions
as you already noticed to be accessed you add `static` modifier, which means you do not need to make instance of class to have access to it `public static` variable.

so, to access variable of one class inside another you need this class be imported and this variable be static. if it not static you should create instance of class before you could have access

```
var newClassInstance = new ClassName();
trace(newClassInstance.varible);
```

the other way is then your class `skin` instance situated inside script.as class... so somewhere inside script.as there is the variable with reference to instance of skin. in that case you could have access to variables of script.as instance using `_parent` from skin.as

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I thought I'd ask anyhow. Thank you for the reply. Chances are I will end up changing the class functions so that I can pass the variable as an argument. It gets to be problematic since there are places where the main script.as file calls to a function in defaultskin.as which then in turn calls to skin.as so I will have to modify both functions as well as change all calls to the functions to include the extra argument. Extra work, but at least it will get the job done without using public variables.

Comment: Updated: Well, I guess you can use the keyword public to declare variables if they are in a class. Guess I'll be rewriting all night to pass the variables along.

Comment: Instead of passing variables itself you could probably pass the reference to class instance to get access to its variables. Making functions that all use argument which always have the same value is not so OOP. But as2 is really not so OOP in many ways...

Comment: How would I pass a reference to the class instance? I have more than two dozen variables that I need to reference inside and outside of the class and that makes passing them as individual variables the real problem and the reason why I don't want to do it. If I can pass the class reference and also gain access to the functions, that would greatly simplify my script as well.

Comment: Lets use proper names. For simplicity class is a some kind of template which contants list of proper data and types for instance of this class. On the other hand instance of this class is object there actual data is stored. For example class is a human being and you and i are actual instances of it class both have same list of properties and functionality but have different values of it.

Comment: I think you don't need pass class reference. If you need access to actual data you need to pass reference to specific instance of class (if we say about classic usage of OOP model). And you could do it by, for example passing reference to other class constructor. Or you could assing this reference as property to any dynamic class instance. If you really sure that you want store data inside static class properties then you don't need pass operations. All you should do is import your static class to script you need and then access any of it property using `ClassName.staticPropertyName` code.